# How to unzip an archive with absolute paths?

Tags: unzip, absolute-path, highlightjs

I have a ZIP file that was obtained from https://highlightjs.org/download - for some inexplicable reason it has absolute pathnames in it:

```
$ unzip -l highlight.zip
Archive:  highlight.zip
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
    38854  08-10-23 22:10   /DIGESTS.md
     1514  08-10-23 22:10   /LICENSE
     1717  08-10-23 22:10   /README.md
        0  08-10-23 22:10   /es/
    76121  08-10-23 22:10   /es/core.js
...
```

It obviously fails to extract, giving `unzip: skipping insecure entry` errors. Is there any way to override this, e.g. `tar` can simply remove the leading `/` and extract the file as a relative path.

**UPDATE:**

Using FreeBSD 13.2 /usr/bin/unzip (has no way to see the version)

Comment: I guess it depends on the version of unzip you're using, but you could try `-j` to "junk" paths and extract to the current directory, or try `-p` on individual files to output to standard output ("pipe"), that you can redirect to a file.

Comment: Did you try the "-d my_dir" option?

Comment: @cj-y - Same result. `mkdir tmp`, `unzip -d tmp highlight.zip` => `unzip: skipping insecure entry`.   I wound up using the `-p` option as suggested by @john-bayko. Was extremely painful as there were hundreds of files and multiple sub-directories. Was able to script it though.

Answer (score 0):

You must have an old version of unzip. Mine (6.0) strips the leading slash, issues a warning, and proceeds to extract into the current directory:

```
Archive:  ../highlight.zip
warning:  stripped absolute path spec from /DIGESTS.md
 extracting: DIGESTS.md
```

I'd recommend that you [update your unzip](https://infozip.sourceforge.net/UnZip.html), which will make your life better in many ways.

You should also let the maintainers of that web site know that their zip files are rude.

Comment: Really old. This was fixed in unzip 5.50 in 2002, over two decades ago!

Comment: [This](https://github.com/madler/zipclean) will fix such zip files.

Comment: This is FreeBSD 13.2 /usr/bin/unzip. There does not seem to be any way to see the version of unzip, as the `-V` and `--version` options don't exist, nor is there any package info since it is part of the FreeBSD base system. I suppose I could download and compile my own unzip but then it would live in my user account - not ideal.

Comment: Oh and as for letting the maintainers know: https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/issues/3835

Comment: Ah, I see. They (FreeBSD) wrote their own subset of unzip for some reason. You could [file a bug](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/) to add an option to write those files with the insecure portions stripped instead of simply rejecting them.